# I cant find information about NFC in KMM

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, nfc, kotlin-multiplatform

I have problem because I can't find how work nfc in kmm. I use sharing viewModels and presentation via JetPackCompose. I want to try implement there if it is possible nfc, I want to use it like a card, but I don't know how to do this. I can't find this on the internet. Meaby I m blind but I try and nothing. Someone can send link to docs or articles when I can teach more about his and how it work or someone can describe a little this topick.

try to find something in the internet.

Comment: Nfc host card emulation is not available to iOS apps. You can read and write tags but you cannot emulate a card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NFC implementations are very hardware specific and very non standard across platforms. How to implement NFC on Android, iOS, Browser and Desktop are very different to each other and each have there own set to restrictions.

In other multi platform develop environments there tends to be third party plugins to support NFC but these are just "IF" based wrappers around a links to native code and they still require you to check your platform and write your own code for each.

Thus you probably won't find anything for NFC related to KMM.

There is of course an Android Kotlin Native API that is available when running as an Android App.